# How to get my Regex function to recognize more substrings

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm new to regular expressions and am currently using the re python library to extract certain fonts embeded in a css file. Currently, my regex formula ignores certain fonts that it should not, but processes other fonts correctly. This is the regex syntax that I am using:

`'font-family\s*?:\s*?(.*?)\s*?[;\}]'`

This is the sample input:

`.ui-block:last-child,.ui-block.last{margin-right:0}body{font-family:"georgia","georgia-1",Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif}.nav-logo-mod{font-family:"league-gothic","league-gothic-1","Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif}.wf-loading .nav-logo{visibility:hidden}.wf-loading .nav-logo.has-img{visibility:visible}.h1,.post-txt h1,.h2,.post-txt h2,.h3,.post-txt h3,.h4,.post-txt h4,.h5,.post-txt h5,.h6,.post-txt h6{line-height:100%;margin-bottom:6px}.h1 a,.post-txt h1 a,a>.h1,.post-txt a>h1,.h2 a,.post-txt h2 a,a>.h2,.post-txt a>h2,.h3 a,.post-txt h3 a,a>.h3,.post-txt a>h3,.h4 a,.post-txt h4 a,a>.h4,.post-txt a>h4,.h5 a,.post-txt h5 a,a>.h5,.post-txt a>h5,.h6 a,.post-txt h6 a,a>.h6,.post-txt a>h6{text-decoration:none}.h1 a:hover,.post-txt h1 a:hover,a>.h1:hover,.post-txt a>h1:hover,.h2 a:hover,.post-txt h2 a:hover,a>.h2:hover,.post-txt a>h2:hover,.h3 a:hover,.post-txt h3 a:hover,a>.h3:hover,.post-txt a>h3:hover,.h4 a:hover,.post-txt h4 a:hover,a>.h4:hover,.post-txt a>h4:hover,.h5 a:hover,.post-txt h5 a:hover,a>.h5:hover,.post-txt a>h5:hover,.h6 a:hover,.post-txt h6 a:hover,a>.h6:hover,.post-txt a>h6:hover{text-decoration:underline}@media (min-width: 450px){.h1,.post-txt h1,.h2,.post-txt h2,.h3,.post-txt h3,.h4,.post-txt h4,.h5,.post-txt h5,.h6,.post-txt h6{line-height:112%}}.h1,.post-txt h1,.h2,.post-txt h2,.h3,.post-txt h3,.h4,.post-txt h4{font-family:"league-gothic","league-gothic-1","Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif;font-weight:normal;line-height:110%}.h5,.post-txt h5,.h6,.post-txt h6{font-family:"georgia","georgia-1",Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif;line-height:140%}.h1,.post-txt h1{font-size:27px}@media (min-width: 500px){.h1,.post-txt h1{font-size:37px}}.h2,.post-txt h2{font-size:25px;margin-bottom:10px}@media (min-width: 500px){.h2,.post-txt h2{font-size:32px}}.h3,.post-txt h3{font-size:1.76923em}.h4,.post-txt h4{font-size:1.30769em}.h5,.post-txt h5{font-size:14px}.h6,.post-txt h6{font-size:12px}.poster-h{font-family:"league-gothic","league-gothic-1","Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif;font-size:38px;line-height:100%;margin-bottom:16px}@media (min-width: 500px){.poster-h{font-size:48px}}.section-h,.section-h1{font:normal 1.23077em/100% "league-gothic","league-gothic-1","Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:4px;padding-bottom:10px;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;margin-bottom:20px}.section-h>a,.section-h1>a{color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;cursor:inherit}.section-h>a:active,.section-h>a:focus,.section-h1>a:active,.section-h1>a:focus{outline:none}.section-h>a:hover,.section-h1>a:hover{text-decoration:underline}.section-h2{font:normal 0.92308em/100% "league-gothic","league-gothic-1","Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:4px;padding-bottom:4px;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;margin-bottom:12px}.section-h2>a{color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;cursor:inherit}.section-h2>a:active,.section-h2>a:focus{outline:none}.section-h2>a:hover{text-decoration:underline}.`

And this is my sample output:

`['Georgia,Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif',"Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif',"Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif', 'Georgia,Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif',"Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif', '"Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif', 'Georgia,Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif', 'Georgia,Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif', '"Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif',"Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif', 'Georgia,Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif', '"Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif', 'Georgia,Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif', 'Georgia,Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif', 'Georgia,Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif', 'Georgia,Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif', 'Georgia,Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif']`

I'd like to include the league-gothic fonts in my output.

Here is my python code:

````
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import re
import sys
import os
if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = sys.argv[1]
    url = url.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(f"http://{url}/")
    time.sleep(5)
    html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
    outfile = open("full_site.html", "w+")
    outfile.write(html)
    outfile.close()
    outfile_path = os.path.abspath("full_site.html")
    driver.get('file://' + outfile_path)
    time.sleep(5)
    elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//link[@href]")
    css_links = []
    font_list = []
    font_file = open("input.txt", "w+")
    font_file.write(url + "\n")
    font_file.close()
    for elem in elems:
        if (("css" in elem.get_attribute("href")) and (elem.get_attribute("href") not in css_links)):
            css_links.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))
    #print(css_links)
    for elem in css_links:
        #print(elem)
        driver.get(elem)
        time.sleep(5)
        lst_of_fonts = []
        html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
        result = re.compile('font-family\s*?:\s*?(.*?)\s*?[;\}]')
        result = re.findall(result, html)
        if result:
            #print(result)
            for element in result:
                element = element.replace("font-family", "").replace("}", "").replace(";", "").replace("{", "").replace(":", "")
                element = element.split(",")
                for font in element:
                    #print(font)
                    font_file = open("input.txt", "a")
                    font_file.write(font + ",")
                #print(font + "\n")
    font_file.close()
    driver.close()```
````

Comment: I can't replicate league-gothic not being included in the results. https://regex101.com/ might be a useful resource for you

Comment: I also verified it matching at regex101.com. If you could add your python code, maybe we can test it that way

Comment: @oppressionslayer I have added my Python code for clarity

Comment: It's matching league=gothic for me, your python compile: re.findall(result, html) ['"georgia","georgia-1",Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif',
 '"league-gothic","league-gothic-1","Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif',
 '"league-gothic","league-gothic-1","Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif',
 '"georgia","georgia-1",Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif',
 '"league-gothic","league-gothic-1","Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif']

Comment: Hmm that's very strange. I'll keep working to find the solution and update if anything comes up. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The input text has some font family names prefixed with just the word `font:` rather than `font-family:`. When `font:` is used, then it has non font-family information, before font family names are listed.  You need to get rid of this extra information.

I think my regex below gets all of the font family names in its capture group 3:

```
import re 

pattern = re.compile(r'font(-family)?:([a-z]+\s\d\.\d+[a-z]+/\d+%)?([^};]*,?)')

results = re.finditer(pattern, text)

for result in results:
    print(result.group(3))
```

Printed output:

> "georgia","georgia-1",Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif
>   "league-gothic","league-gothic-1","Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif
>   "league-gothic","league-gothic-1","Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif
>   "georgia","georgia-1",Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif
>   "league-gothic","league-gothic-1","Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif
>    "league-gothic","league-gothic-1","Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif
>    "league-gothic","league-gothic-1","Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif